# %1 is not a valid Win32 application (lnk file)

Tags: python

I have this script in python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call( 'pathtofile/file.lnk')
```

and i got this error

> WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I find out that it needs exe files in order to work.Is there any way that i can do it with **lnk** and **mdb** files?

Comment: Check this library https://pypi.org/project/pylnk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute a shortcut or an mdb file. You probably want to do the equivalent of double-clicking the file in Windows. This opens the file in the default application.

To do that, you can use [os.startfile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: Thank you so much!That's what i wanted :D